# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal in PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I search through the numerous questions already asked about the "unterminated string literal" syntax error but found nothing helping me ...

So, I have this Javascript function :

```
function parametresModal($parametres) {
        document.getElementById('remodalTest').innerHTML = $parametres;
};
```

Then I call this function on a link in my page :

```
<a href="#" onClick='parametresModal("<?php the_field('description-defi'); ?>");'>TEST</a>
```

The parameter written here is simplified ; I actually want to add this Wordpress ACF's function among others and HTML markup, but I found the issue was appearing with this particular field (see below).

This "parametresModal" function is supposed to fill the following div with its parameters :

```
<div id="remodalTest">MyDiv</div>
```

Problem is the console outputs

> "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal"

The Wordpress ACF's field "description-defi" contains a few lines of text with some simple quotes (ex. c**'**est, l**'**éviter, ...).
So I tried to escape the quotes with several methods :

```
$myField = the_field('description-defi');
$myEscape = json_encode($myField);
```

or

```
$myField = the_field('description-defi');
$myEscape = addshlashes($myField);
```

or

```
$myField = the_field('description-defi');
$myEscape = htmlspecialchars($myField);
```

Always resulting in the same error.

Do you see where I could be wrong in my code or my way of thinking the thing ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: @FetraR. According to the docs `the_field()` is equal to `echo get_field()`

Comment: @FetraR. that would be effectively what he is doing right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_field()` will output the content of the selected field. If you want to work with a field, you should use `get_field()` instead.

See: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

Also the newline character will not be escaped by any of PHP's escape functions, if your String contains newlines, you will need to escape them manually using something like this: `$myField = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), "<br>", $myField);`.

If you know that your DB will consistently use the same newline sequence, you can replace `array("\r\n", "\n")` by that newline sequence instead.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
I already tried with

`$myField = get_field('description-defi');`

and escaping $myField, but I got the same error.

Comment: (When I told about escaping $myField, I meant with the same "methods" as described in the question : htmlspecialchars, json_encode and addslashes)

Comment: Try to also `$myField = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), "<br>", $myField);`, as accodring to the docs none of PHP's escape function escape newline characters.

Comment: Great, it works ! Thank you very much ! 
(Do you want to post this as an answer so I can accept it ? ;) )

Comment: Edited my answer :)

Comment: Thanks again ! ;)